# Outline image markersymbol in esri maps

Tags: buffer, markers, outline

I have a marker , i need to populate the same with ouline color ,

var bufferedArea = geometryEngine.buffer(results[x].geometry, 1);
var bufferedGraphic = new Graphic(bufferedArea, BufferSymbol);
map.graphics.add(bufferedGraphic);

but this is not helping for now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a feature layer showing different markers at extent, i will initialize a toolbar with selection of feature layer , it selects the marker and i get the attribute from the same layer , but the issue is i need to outline that marker with red color as border color. 
i tried above approach but of no success.